# Как узнать где находится исполняемый файл node js внутри node?

Tags: node.js

Как внутри node js программы, узнать где в системе находится исполняемый node js файл?
Чтобы затем запускать их через spawn например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем? Есть же `child_process.fork`.

Впрочем, если очень надо, то в `process.execPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `process.cwd()` возвращает абсолютный путь к папке, в которой вы находились в момент запуска команды `node app.js` (ну или `npm run start`, что там у вас).
Нужно помнить, что ваш исполняемый файл может лежать на некотором уровне вложенности относительно папки исполнения команды (например `node ./dist/app.js`).